# How do I send push notifications in Reactjs on Android

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, web-applications, push-notification

The scenario is this:

Announcements will be written through Google Spreadsheet and will be retrieved on the web app page (which is I'm using is React JS)

I need to let the user know that there's a new announcement

How do I implement push notification from that

I've tried using Firebase Cloud Messaging but I can't figure out how the JSON works

[here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1/) is the link is used as reference

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "ID here"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Push-notification.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

export const initializeFirebase = () => {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "demo",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "ID",
    appId: "app id"
  });

  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then((registration) => {
      firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration);
    });
}

export const firebaseNotifications = async () => {
    try {
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      await messaging.requestPermission();
      const token = await messaging.getToken();
      console.log('Token:', token);

      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

All the code I used is in the link given

There are still no errors encountered. But I've hit a roadblock and that I can't seem to work this out.

Comment: It'll be hard to help without having a proper code view of the related code snaps you are using to do this.

Comment: Also, if you are willing to do this with React, you will need to implement PWA workers to your app to be able to push notifications to Android.

Comment: @SultanH. there ya go 
dats all i've used for Push Notifications

Im not entirely sure yet about PWA workers
but I think my web app is PWA 
(because it... looks like an app when I add it to my phone home screen)

Comment: I got it! The answer to this question is right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068740/how-to-send-post-data-coming-from-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and just follow properly the setup in firebase

and use postman to send JSON parameters to test the push notification to your android