# How to send POST data coming from Google Apps Script?

Tags: reactjs, post, google-apps-script, push-notification

I used Firebase Cloud Messaging as a way to have push notifications in my web app. 
So now I am using Postman as a way to send my push notifications but *i only send it manually*

From google apps script I need to send my push notification.

This is what I use in Postman which has no problem and it works

[image]

This is from my Google apps script

```
function firebaseNotification() {

  var headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "key=key",
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  };

  var options =
   {
      "notification": {
        "title": "CWMS",
        "body": "from google apps scritpt",
        "click_action": "site",
        "icon": "http://url-to-an-icon/icon.png"
    },
    "to": "key"
   };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", options);  

}
```

What needs to happen is that from Google Apps Script `function firebaseNotification()` but be triggered there and can POST the data needed and the web app to receive the push notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function firebaseNotification() {
  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "key=key"
  };

  // Modified
  var payload = {
    "notification": {
      "title": "CWMS",
      "body": "from google apps scritpt",
      "click_action": "site",
      "icon": "http://url-to-an-icon/icon.png"
    },
    "to": "key"
  };

  // Modified
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload) // <--- Modified
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", options);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

If this modification didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, please check the parameters for authorizing again.

Comment: I have an error that says 

`Request failed for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send returned code 400. Truncated server response: JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0. (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 195, file "script")`

Line 195 is `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", options);`

Comment: @Olufsen Thank you for replying. I noticed a spelling miss of `payload`. I apologize for this. I modified it. Could you please confirm it? `paload: JSON.stringify(payload)` is `payload: JSON.stringify(payload)`.

Comment: Ah I didnt noticed that too! I thought Firebase blocks request from Apps Script 

its working now . Thank you!